# Replace all the values in a certain column with certain values using csv reader Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

This is the question continous from my previous question.
Thank to many people, I could modify my code as below.

```
import csv
with open("SURFACE2", "rb") as infile, open("output.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        row[18] = "999"                  

        writer.writerow(row)
```

I just change delimiter from "\t" to " ". Whiel with previous delimiter, the code only worked upto row[0], with " " the code can work until row[18].

```
15.20000           120.60000 98327      get data information here.  SURFACE DATA FROM ??????????? SOURCE    FM-12 SYNOP                                                                                155.00000         1         0         0         0         0         T         F         F   -888888   -888888      20020601030000 100820.00000
```

From the data line above, row[18] is just in the middle between 15.20000 and 120.60000.

I am not sure what happens in between these two values. Maybe delimiter changes? However visually I can't notice any difference. 
Is there any way which I can know the delimiter changed and if so, do you have any idea to handle multiple delimiter for one code?

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,
Isaac

---

The results from repr(next(infile)):

```
'            15.20000           120.60000 98327      get data information here.  SURFACE DATA FROM ??????????? SOURCE    FM-12 SYNOP                                                                                155.00000         1         0         0         0         0         T         F         F   -888888   -888888      20020601030000 100820.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'  99070.00000      0    155.00000      0    303.20001      0    297.79999      0      3.00000      0    140.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'-777777.00000      0-777777.00000      0      1.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'      1      0      0\n'
'            55.10000            -3.60000 03154      get data information here.  SURFACE DATA FROM ??????????? SOURCE    FM-12 SYNOP                                                                                 16.00000         1         0         0         0         0         T         F         F   -888888   -888888      20020601030000-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'-888888.00000      0     16.00000      0    281.20001      0    279.89999      0      0.00000      0      0.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'-777777.00000      0-777777.00000      0      1.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0\n'
'      1      0      0\n'
```

As you can see  actually four first lines should be one line. For some reason, full line seems divided into 4 parts.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you,
Isaac

Comment: Can you clarify what it means when you say "the code can now work until row[18]"?

Comment: I don't understand your question - what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @AndrewMagee It means when I use row[18], this code works and no errors, but when I use row[19] it shows " list assignment index out of range" error. Thank you.

Comment: Ok so maybe there are exactly 19 fields in the row (row[18] being the last one)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sorry for confusion. I would like to change all the value in the column. So, row[18] means that I would like to change value in the column with 999. Upto row[18], this code works well, but when I would like to change 20th column with row[19], it shows "index out of range" error. Thank you.

Comment: There must be a row that just doesn't have that many columns. In your loop you can say `print(len(row))` to see how many columns there are in each row.

Comment: @AndrewMagee That is the possible reason, but as you can see the data line above, this data line has very long length. Actually what I would like to change is almost about row[50].

Comment: Right but the elements in the list `row` are fields, not characters.

Comment: @AndrewMagee Thank you Andrew, I will follow your advice.

Comment: @AndrewMagee as you recommended, I tried to see the len(row}. However, interesting thing is that len(row)s for each row are all different which should not be. Maybe csv.reader is not the correct tool, Would you please any other tool for replace? Thank you.

Comment: What does the line that you are having trouble with look like when you print with `repr()`? The code that you posted will work only for fields that are delimited by a single space character. This means that fields like "get data information here" will result in multiple fields. Where does the CSV file come from? Is there a spec for it?

Comment: @mhawke yes some lines are shorther not including all columns. This is not actually CSV file, but ascill file which is formatted in a certain form for the atmospheric observation.'

Comment: @mhawke I put the "repr()" result below in the answer by myself, because the result, even the part of it, is too long. Would you please comment on it?

Comment: @Isaac did the data originally have tabs in it? Should the line really be, eg, `"15.20000\t120.60000\t98327\tget data information here..."`?

Comment: @AndrewMagee: no, I don't think so. The data comes from a weather observation data format known as "little_r". It is not a CSV file, more like a fixed width field padded with spaces.

Comment: Ah. Well if it's fixed width then the `csv` module is definitely inappropriate. What you want to do is plug the field widths into a pattern like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914089/223486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N.B.** The file format is discussed on page 19 of this [document](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/wrfda/Tutorials/2012_July/docs/WRFDA_obsproc.pdf). This more-or-less agrees with the sample data.

**EDIT**

OK, after considering the various comments, additional answers, and reading the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734402/replace-all-values-in-a-certain-column-with-one-value-python) it would seem that the file in question is not a CSV file. It is weather observation data formatted as "little_r" which uses fixed width fields padded with spaces. There is not much info available so I'm guessing, but each group of 4 lines seem to comprise a single observation. From your previous question it seems that you want to update the 3rd column in the first line? The other 3 lines would be skipped. Then update the 3rd column in the first line of the next set of 4 lines, etc., etc.

An example from the OP:

```
            15.20000           120.60000 98327      get data information here.  SURFACE DATA FROM ??????????? SOURCE    FM-12 SYNOP                                                                                155.00000         1         0         0         0         0         T         F         F   -888888   -888888      20020601030000 100820.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0
  99070.00000      0    155.00000      0    303.20001      0    297.79999      0      3.00000      0    140.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0
-777777.00000      0-777777.00000      0      1.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0-888888.00000      0
      1      0      0
```

The first 2 columns of the first line are (I'm guessing) the latitude and longitude for the observations. I have no idea what the 3rd column `98327` is, but this is the column that the OP wants to update (based on previous question).

It's not a CSV file, so don't process it as one. Instead, because there are fixed width fields, we know the offset and width of the field that needs to be updated. Based on the sample data the 3rd column occupies characters 41-46. So, to update the data and write to a new file:

```
offset_col_3 = 41
length_col_3 = 5

with open('SURFACE2') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(infile):
        if line_no % 4 == 0:    # every 4th line starting with the first
            line = '{}{:>5}{}'.format(line[:offset_col_3], 999, line[offset_col_3+length_col_3:])
        outfile.write(line)
```

---

**Original answer**

Try reading line 20 (row[19]) (assuming no header line in the CSV file, otherwise line 21) from the file and inspecting it in Python:

```
with open("SURFACE2") as infile:
    for i in range(20):
        print repr(next(infile))
```

The last line displayed will be row 18. If, for example, tabs are delimiters then you might see `\t` in between the columns of data. Compare the previous line to the last line to see if there is a difference in the delimiter used.

If you find that your CSV file is mixing delimiters, then you might have to split the fields manually.

Comment: He doesn't seem to be talking about row 18 but rather column 18 in a particular row.

Comment: @AndrewMagee. Oh, well if rows and columns are being confused then it's a difficult to know what is being asked.

Comment: @mhawke Sorry for confusion, actually I would like to change the column not line or row. Thank you.

Comment: @Isaac : no problem. This answer is still useful for you to inspect the data.

Comment: Well since my post was deleted by the moderator I assume that means we do not need no one else around here.  That is what I have been in the USMC for the past 10 years, where we can handle things like that  as gentlemen in a secluded location. I do this in good faith but your answer is helpful mine is not. Sorry kid but the Tyranny of the Majority has spoken. I do not live from programming, that is why I can live for it, by pure interest, but that is not helpful around here, got it, enjoy.

Comment: I spent near 10 hours editing and adding information to that post, but that annoys people and take some valuable resources that we can spend on your answers. Again thank you assholes, enjoy.

Comment: @Schopenhauer I am sorry. I am not sure how your answer was deletted. I appreciate your concern and help.

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module is not the right tool to use when you have fixed-width fields in your file. What you need to do is explicitly use the field lengths to split up the lines. For example:

```
# This would be your whole file
data = "\n".join([
    "abc  def gh i",
    "jk   lm  n  o",
    "p    q   r  s",
])
field_widths = [5, 4, 3, 1]

def fields(line, field_widths):
    pos = 0
    for length in field_widths:
        yield line[pos:pos + length].strip()
        pos += length

for line in data.split("\n"):
    print(list(fields(line, field_widths)))
```

will give you:

```
['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'i']
['jk', 'lm', 'n', 'o']
['p', 'q', 'r', 's']
```

Comment: thank you, I will try your solution and let you know the results.